# How to increment a value in MySQL? I want to find student grade that max tot must be 1 and so on

Tags: mysql

[image]

I want increment a value after every cycle after every row @a value must be incremented

```
SET @a=1;

SELECT  
    @a, std_id,
    SUM(`read_mark` + `write_mark` + `homework` + `classwork`) AS tot 
FROM 
    tbl_exam
WHERE
    `class_detail_id` = 26 
    AND YEAR(`date`) = 1397 
GROUP BY 
    `std_id` 
ORDER BY
    SUM(`read_mark` + `write_mark` + `homework` + `classwork`) DESC;

SET @a = @a + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
SET @a = 0;

select (@a:=@a + 1) AS num,* from
(SELECT 
    std_id,SUM(`read_mark`+`write_mark`+`homework`+`classwork`) AS tot 
    FROM tbl_exam
    where `class_detail_id`=26 AND YEAR(`date`)=1397 GROUP BY `std_id` 
   ORDER BY tot  DESC
)X
```

For MYSql Version 8+ you can use window function row_number()

```
select row_number() over(partition by std_id order by tot desc) as num,*
from
(SELECT 
        std_id,SUM(`read_mark`+`write_mark`+`homework`+`classwork`) AS tot 
        FROM tbl_exam
        where `class_detail_id`=26 AND YEAR(`date`)=1397 GROUP BY `std_id` 
       ORDER BY tot  DESC
 )X
```

Comment: @AbdulhadiAfghan, can you please add your expected output in the question so that people can unnderstand how you want the output